# ruby on rails forces show after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm editing a record and receive a constraint related error after hitting "Save". Then I correct the form field involved and click "Save". Ruby on Rails forces me to the show action whilst I'd rather stay on the edit form. Is this by design or I'm (hopefully) missing something here ?

controller

```
  def update
      @profile_field = safe_find ProfileField, params[:id], "profile field"
      if @profile_field.update_attributes(input_params)
        logger.tagged("#{self.class} #{__method__}") {logger.info @profile_field.inspect }
        flash[:success] = "profile field updated"
        redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
  end
```

view

```
= form_for @profile_field do |f|
  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object 

  .field
    = f.label :name_en
    = f.text_field :name_en
    = f.label :name_et
    = f.text_field :name_et
    = f.label :name_ru
    = f.text_field :name_ru
    = f.label :field_type
    = f.select :field_type, options_for_select(ProfileField.field_types, 
    :selected => f.object.field_type), :default => f.object.field_type
    = button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block') do
      %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-floppy-disk
      Save
    = link_to profile_fields_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-block" do
      %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-left
      Back
```

Comment: Redirect to the edit page instead?

Comment: Thanks for spending your time on a newbie @Dave Newton